# Programmatically changing WPF TextBox's Text with regard of cursor position and current selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, numpad

I am implementing some sort of NumericKeypad Control for my WPF application which clients can use to conviniently enter text with a Touchscreen.

The Control itself runs fine, I even managed to run the Control (which is a Window) in the foreground while the TextBox, which is the target of the input, retains the focus and selection.

Now, I want to add the user's input into the TextBox's Text property just like if he had entered them with a keyboard. That means that certain behaviors should be adhered to, for instance...

- When the cursor is inbetween the Text, the character should be placed to where the cursor currently resides.
- When something is selected, the selection should be replaced with the entered character.

Is there anything I can use to do that? The only function I found is [TextBoxBase.AppendText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx), which does not consider the cursor position or selection, but simply appends the entered String to the end of the Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TextBox.SelectedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_TextBox_SelectedText), which has both a setter and a getter.

If no text is selected, `SelectedText` is the zero-length range at the caret position.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Did not think it would be that easy.